# JavaScript UL Vertical Text

Tags: javascript, html-lists

What I am trying to achieve is to have javascript take an UL and write each LI vertically like so:

```
  O  T  T  F
  N  W  H  O
  E  O  R  U
        E  R
        E
```

I can style the list with css, but i need to do the vertical writing with JavaScript. I'm not very good with JavaScript, could anyone please help me out with this? Or point me to an example?

Thanks

Edit - Sorry I should of been more clear about what I am trying to do. I have some js that takes a list and sorts it alphabetically when clicking a button. I would like the list to display normal until the button is clicked. Then it should display the text in alphabeticle order and write the text vertically. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cates044/CFwJL/27/)

Comment: Do the lists have to remain as `<ul>` lists or can we convert them to a `<table>`?

Comment: I think using list elements is probably better in terms of web standards and good practice. We should not be preaching bad practice.

Comment: Oh I just mean for formatting via JavaScript, you could have `<LI>`s in the source but can we use JavaScript to take each letter and build a table from them

Comment: Is there a way I could add a class to the ul li that could become active once the button is pressed or something?

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS for the vertical writing:

```
width:1px;
word-break:break-all;
```

You may need to adjust margins to ensure that letters have enough room.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you could simply make the li element only wide enough to fit one character per line and use margins and padding to do the rest.

Comment: Sorry I edited my question. The problem with this is that I want the li to display normal until a button is clicked. Thanks

Comment: Well first things first. Go to http://www.jslint.com/ and lint your code. I just put your JavaScript in there and there were enough errors to make it stop after it had only scanned 28%.